# TypeScript typeof Function return value

Tags: typescript

Admit I have a function like this

```
const createPerson = () => ({ firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' })
```

How can I, **without declaring an interface or a type** before declaring `createPerson`, get the return value type?

Something like this:

```
type Person = typeof createPerson()
```

---

### Example Scenario

I have a Redux container that maps state and dispatch actions to props of a component.

#### containers/Counter.tsx

```
import { CounterState } from 'reducers/counter'

// ... Here I also defined MappedState and mapStateToProps

// The interface I would like to remove
interface MappedDispatch {
  increment: () => any
}

// And get the return value type of this function
const mapDispatchToProps =
  (dispatch: Dispatch<State>): MappedDispatch => ({
    increment: () => dispatch(increment)
  })

// To export it here instead of MappedDispatch
export type MappedProps = MappedState & MappedDispatch
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Counter)
```

#### components/Counter.tsx

```
import { MappedProps } from 'containers/Counter'

export default (props: MappedProps) => (
  <div>
    <h1>Counter</h1>
    <p>{props.value}</p>
    <button onClick={props.increment}>+</button>
  </div>
)
```

I want to be able to export the type of `mapDispatchToProps` without having to create `MappedDispatch` interface.

I reduced the code here, but it makes me type the same thing two times.

Comment: Why? What's the point? Can you add a scenario in which it makes sense?

Comment: I don't think that you can do that. There's no way of defining a type based on the type of a return value of a function.

Answer (score 239, accepted):

## Original Post

### TypeScript < 2.8

I created a little library that permits a workaround, until a fully declarative way is added to TypeScript:

https://npmjs.com/package/returnof

Also created an issue on Github, asking for **Generic Types Inference**, that would permit a fully declarative way to do this:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14400

---

## Update February 2018

### TypeScript 2.8

TypeScript 2.8 introduced a new static type `ReturnType` which permits to achieve that:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21496

You can now easily get the return type of a function in a fully declarative way:

```
const createPerson = () => ({
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe'
})

type Person = ReturnType<typeof createPerson>
```

Comment: How can I get the return type of a method when using clases? I can't use `ReturnType<typeof this.methodName>`

Comment: @IvánSánchez For a class Animal you can do `ReturnType<Animal['methodName']>`, or `ReturnType<this['methodName']>` inside a class method.

Comment: And to get ReturnType of a *static method*: `ReturnType<(typeof Animal)['methodName']>`

Comment: For anyone wondering, if your function uses generics this likely won't solve your problem.

Answer (score 17):

This https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4233#issuecomment-139978012 might help:

```
let r = true ? undefined : someFunction();
type ReturnType = typeof r;
```

Comment: With recent strict null checks, the following avoids the (undefined | ...) part:
`
let r = true ? (undefined as never) : someFunction();
type ReturnType = typeof r;
`

Answer (score 13):

Adapted from https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14400#issuecomment-291261491

```
const fakeReturn = <T>(fn: () => T) => ({} as T)

const hello = () => 'World'
const helloReturn = fakeReturn(hello) // {}

type Hello = typeof helloReturn // string
```

The example in the link uses `null as T` instead of `{} as T`, but that breaks with `Type 'null' cannot be converted to type 'T'.`

The best part is that the function given as parameter to `fakeReturn` is not actually called.

Tested with TypeScript 2.5.3

---

TypeScript 2.8 introduced some predefined conditional types, including the `ReturnType<T>` that obtains the return type of a function type.

```
const hello = () => 'World'

type Hello = ReturnType<typeof hello> // string
```