# TypeScript. How to use not exported type definitions?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Just look at this typescript code:

---

lib.ts

```
interface Human {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

export default class HumanFactory {
    getHuman(): Human {
        return {
            name: "John",
            age: 22,
        }
    }
}
```

---

index.ts

```
import HumanFactory from "./lib";

export class Foo {
    human: any;

    constructor() {
        const factory = new HumanFactory();
        this.human = factory.getHuman();
    }

    diffWithError(age: number): number {
        return age - this.human.name;
    }

    diffWithTypingAndAutocoplete(age: number): number {
        const factory = new HumanFactory();
        return age - factory.getHuman().name;
    }
}
```

The problem in "human" property of "Foo" class. I can't define type of this variable as "Human" interface from lib.ts.

In method "diffWithError" I make an error - use number "age" and string "name" in arithmetic operation, but neither IDE nor ts compiler know about this, because in this context, type of "this.human.name" is "any"

In method "diffWithTypingAndAutocoplete" I just use method "getHuman". IDE and compiler know about type of method result. This is "Human" interface and field "name" are "string". This method trigger an error when compiling sources.

---

I found this problem when I tried import .d.ts file of JS lib and I don't have ability to export needed interface. Can I somehow define valid type of "human" property without copy and paste code of "Human" interface whenever i want to define type (and without inline type definitions, like { name: string, age: number }).

I don not want to create instances of not exported classes, I just want type checking and autocomplete.

---

P.S. I try write this:

```
human: Human
```

compiler trigger an error: "error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Human'" (expected behavior)

---

P.S.S I try to do this with triple slash directive:

```
///<reference path="./lib.ts" />
```

but this not working too.

---

Sorry for my poor english and thanks for answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

Now with [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#predefined-conditional-types) in place it can be done without workarounds:

```
type Human = ReturnType<HumanFactory['getHuman']>
```

---

**Workaround** for TS < 2.8

If you can't change *lib.ts* you can "query" return type of `getHuman` function. It is a bit tricky because typescript currently doesn't provide any straight forward method for this:

```
import HumanFactory from "./lib";

const dummyHuman = !true && new HumanFactory().getHuman();
type Human = typeof dummyHuman;

export class Foo {
  human: Human;

  // ...
}
```

`!true &&` is used to prevent `new HumanFactory().getHuman()` execution.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work: `error TS2322: Type 'Human' is not assignable to type 'false'.` triggered when I try this `this.human = factory.getHuman()` in constructor

Comment: Which version of typescript do you use?

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution!

I make file human-interface.ts with this content:

```
import HumanFactory from './lib';

const humanObject = new HumanFactory().getHuman();
type HumanType = typeof humanObject;

export default interface Human extends HumanType {}
```

Import of this interface in main file not execute creation of "HumanFactory" and type checking work properly.

Thanks for idea with `typeof`

Comment: This is not a good solution, you should not create an unnecessary object for merely getting a type.

Answer (score 2):

You need to export `Human` so that it is visible - and usable - from `index.ts` as well (as `HumanFactory`). Do not use default exports but "named exports" i.e. try this

```
export interface Human {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

export class HumanFactory {
    getHuman(): Human {
        return {
            name: "John",
            age: 22,
        }
    }
}
```

In `index.ts`

```
import { Human, HumanFactory} from "./lib";
```

** EDIT **

If you cannot change `lib.d.ts` then redefine `Human` and use double-casting i.e.

```
import HumanFactory from "./lib";

interface Human {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

export class Foo {
    human: Human;  // <= change here

    constructor() {
        const factory = new HumanFactory();
        this.human = factory.getHuman() as any as Human;  // <= double casting 
    }

    diffWithError(age: number): number {
        return age - this.human.name;
    }

    diffWithTypingAndAutocoplete(age: number): number {
        const factory = new HumanFactory();
        return age - factory.getHuman().name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't edit `lib.ts`. In my project this is type definition of external library in .d.ts file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46774999/8779223) acceptable for me

Answer (score 0):

This was made easier with the introduction of the `ReturnType<>` static type in TypeScript 2.8.

```
import HumanFactory from "./lib";
type Human = ReturnType<typeof HumanFactory.prototype.getHuman>
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/43053162