# Cannot pass Class to helper method

Tags: tsc, typescript3.0

I have this which compiles:

```
export namespace Foo {
   export namespace GET {
       export namespace Basic {
          export class Req {}
       }
   }
}

type Req = Foo.GET.Basic.Req;
e.setRequestBodyType(Foo.GET.Basic.Req);
```

what I would like do is, is reduce it to one line, like so:

```
type Req = typeof e.setRequestBodyType(Foo.GET.Basic.Req);
```

However, I am getting this error:

[image]

tsc --watch just says this:

> express-test.ts:34:37 - error TS1005: ';' expected.
>
> 34   type Req = typeof e.setRequestType(Foo.GET.Basic.Req);

Does anyone know how to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Right now the helper method just looks like:

```
  setRequestType(v:any){
    return v;
  }
```

I tried this:

```
  setRequestType<T>(v:T): T{
    return v;
  }
```

But then I get:

[image]
                                 ~

Weird.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript typeof Function return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40590034/typescript-typeof-function-return-value)

Answer (score 1):

The `typeof` type operator only accepts identifiers, not method calls.

See the [spec](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.8.10).